# How to scale the repository pattern in Scala?

Tags: scala, repository-pattern

We're using the repository pattern for our data access in Scala and so far we have something like this in our `Repository[A]` trait:

```
trait Repository[A] {

  /**
    * Create a new record in the database.
    *
    * @param model
    * @param connection
    * @return
    */
  def create(model: A)(implicit connection: Connection): A

  /**
    * Retrieve a record from the database with the corresponding id.
    *
    * @param id
    * @param connection
    * @return
    */
  def getById(id: UUID)(implicit connection: Connection): Option[A]

  /**
    * Update the corresponding record in the database.
    *
    * @param model
    * @param connection
    * @return The updated model, or None if it was not found
    */
  def update(model: A)(implicit connection: Connection): Option[A]

  /**
    * Delete a record from the database with the corresponding id.
    *
    * @param id
    * @param connection
    * @return The deleted model, or None if it was not found
    */
  def deleteById(id: UUID)(implicit connection: Connection): Option[A]

}
```

And that's fine. This issue is with the "query" methods. For example, imagine I have a method for getting all blog posts where:

- the user id is X, or
- the user is a guest

I also want to include the blog object. Under our current system, we would have a method like this:

```
def getWithBlogByUserIdOrUserGuest(userId: UUID, guest: Boolean): List[Post]
```

This is pretty ugly, and if you want to return a bunch of relations with an entity (that have long names) it can get out of hand quickly. It's also hard to use an trait to add some sort of consistency.

Some examples I've seen only are to use a query object:

```
def query(criteria: Criteria): List[A]
```

However, this requires coming up with some sort of DSL for defining criteria, and it also requires writing code that converts the criteria to SQL which is error prone and a lot of work, and will probably suck.

So, my question is, how do most people deal with having some sort of generalized way to write query methods in repositories?

Comment: This depends hugely on what you mean by "generalised". If you mean more-or-less-equivalent to SQL then that's a bit ask.  But are you prematurely optimising? What kind of queries will you really get in your application? And in some cases, is it best for the client to do a simpler query and further filter the results itself?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: Right now we have actual methods like `getOneWithWidgetAndTaskTemplateByChecklistRevisionIdAndWidgetId` and I'm looking for a better way to do it than that. It doesn't need to be a general criteria API, but just some more manageable way of defining the methods.

Comment: Do they *need* to be that generic?  In my experience there usually ends up only a few ways it makes sense for your business code to retrieve objects so just code those methods.  YAGNI applies!

Comment: Sure, I understand you have complex queries. I'm asking whether you have enough different queries to justify a generalised way of representing them. As @Paolo says, just code the ones you have.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured it out you can implement the "Query Object".

As to not *"writing code that converts the criteria to SQL which is error prone and a lot of work"* you can use a framework like [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/), which will do all the SQL generation for you and allows you to treat tables as collections and do things like:

```
posts.filter(post => post.userId == "USER-ID-1" || post.guest)
```

Slick's `abstract class Query` has a HOF called `filter`, so you can pass in your custom function to it to determine whether a record should be filtered out or not.